# Strange ruby for loop behavior (why does this work)

Tags: ruby, for-loop

```
def reverse(ary)
  result = []
  for result[0,0] in ary
  end
  result
end

assert_equal ["baz", "bar", "foo"], reverse(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
```

This works and I want to understand why.  Any explanations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I were to rewrite this using `each` instead of `for/in`, it would look like this:

```
def reverse(ary)
  result = []

  # for result[0,0] in ary
  ary.each do |item|
    result[0, 0] = item
  end

  result
end
```

`for a in b` basically says, take each item in the array `b` and assign it to expression `a`.  So some magic happens when its not a simple variable.

The `array[index, length] = something` syntax allows replacement of multiple items, even 0 items.  So `ary[0,0] = item` says to insert `item` at index zero, replacing zero items.  It's basically an `unshift` operation.

---

But really, just use the `each` method with a block instead. A for loop with no body that changes state has to be one of the most obtuse and hard to read thing that doesn't do what you expect at first glance.  `each` provides far fewer crazy surprises.

Comment: It is entirely obtuse and I would NEVER do it.  I saw it on a ruby puzzles site and found the answer but could not for the life of me figure out why it worked.  This is a great explanation, though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You are putting the value in ary at the first location of result. So lets say we had the array:
`a = ["baz", "bar", "foo"]`

So `a[0,0] = 5` will make `a` equal to `[5, "baz", "bar", "foo"]`

Since you iterate over the entire array, you are inserting each element into the beginning of the result array while shifting the existing elements, thus reversing the original one.